# Javascript Vertical Carousel with Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, infinite-loop

I'm trying to build a fullscreen vertical carousel` for a personal photography portfolio and so far I've created a simple vertical slider with the help of a tutorial.

I wanted to make it so that upon reaching the final element, if I click on "button-down" the carousel displays the first child again without scrolling all the way back to the top and vice-versa. Please keep in mind that I'm relatively new to web development so any help and feedback is greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
        <div class="carousel-content">
            <div class="carousel-item active-item">
                <img loading="lazy" class="carousel-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x350/0bf?text=image1" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img loading="lazy" class="carousel-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x350/0bf?text=image2" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img loading="lazy" class="carousel-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x350/0bf?text=image3" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img loading="lazy" class="carousel-image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x350/0bf?text=image4" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-button button-up">
            <img src="media/arrow-sm-up-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-button button-down">
            <img src="media/arrow-sm-down-svgrepo-com.svg" alt="">
        </button>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.carousel-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
}

.carousel-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.carousel-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    scale: 5;
}

.button-down {
    left: 50px;
}

.button-up {
    right: 50px;
}

.carousel-button img {
    width: 12px;
}
```

Javascript (without any loop)

```
const track = document.querySelector('.carousel-content');
const slides = Array.from(track.children);

const slideDownButton = document.querySelector('.button-down');
const slideUpButton = document.querySelector('.button-up');

const slideHeight = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;

const setSlidePosition = (slide, index) => {
    slide.style.top = slideHeight * index + 'px';
};
slides.forEach(setSlidePosition);

const moveToSlide = (track, currentSlide, targetSlide) => {
    track.style.transform = 'translateY(-' + targetSlide.style.top + ')';
    currentSlide.classList.remove('active-item');
    targetSlide.classList.add('active-item');
}

slideUpButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const currentSlide = track.querySelector('.active-item');
    const nextSlide = currentSlide.previousElementSibling;

    moveToSlide(track, currentSlide, nextSlide);
});

slideDownButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const currentSlide = track.querySelector('.active-item');
    const nextSlide = currentSlide.nextElementSibling;

    moveToSlide(track, currentSlide, nextSlide);
});
```

I tried giving the nextSlide variable the position for either end of the carousel but it makes the carousel slide all the way across to the end or to the top.

```
slideUpButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const currentSlide = track.querySelector('.active-item');
    const nextSlide = currentSlide.previousElementSibling || slides[slides.length - 1];

    moveToSlide(track, currentSlide, nextSlide);
});

slideDownButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const currentSlide = track.querySelector('.active-item');
    const nextSlide = currentSlide.nextElementSibling || slides[0];

    moveToSlide(track, currentSlide, nextSlide);
});
```

Comment: Hi there. have you simply tried setting the next slide to the slide[0] if you've reached the slides[slides.length - 1]?

Comment: Hi. You can try to add at the end of setSlidePosition() a condition statement when you reach the last slide (index===slides.length-1) that will set index to 0